# Eclipse WebLogic Plugin problem - can't start WebLogic server

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I am running Eclipse v3.4.1 with weblogic plugin (Oracle Server Tools v1.2.0.200907171310). I am running Oracle Weblogic 10gR3 locally.

On the server tab within Eclipse, I click the Start Server button but receive the following error message:

**'startWebLogic.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I think this has somehting to do with my Eclipse environment because when I run the same startup script from outside the IDE on the command line, it runs and starts the server successfully.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

That error message sounds like the one that comes from Windows when you try to run a file, and Windows can't find it.  For example, see [this blog post](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2008/01/xxx-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or.html); or just enter a nonsense command on the cmd.exe command line, and you'll get a similar error message.

Maybe your Eclipse is somehow running with a different PATH than your cmd.exe command window?

Comment: Jon,

Thanks for the reply. How do I check/change my PATH in Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: @JamesB - Good question, I don't actually know!  Another thought, although it might be using a sledgehammer to solve a much smaller problem: You could try using a tool like Filemon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to see where (at what location(s)) Eclipse is looking for the startWebLogic.cmd file -- that might give you a clue.

Answer (score 2):

Jon,

I have solved the problem.

I found this thread which describes problems using Tomcat with Eclipse:

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5368347

Anyway, I deleted the pref files as suggested at the bottom of this forum thread. I then used the wizard in Eclipse to setup a new Server and it now starts/stops perfectly through the IDE. I'm unsure how Eclipse got into this state in the first place mind.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool, glad you got the problem fixed.  And thanks for sharing your solution, hopefully it will be helpful to others.